# How to get the IBKR TWS API to recognize the Path that has been added to the Environment Variable through python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, scripting, parallels

Basically I have Installed Python, TWS Desktop app, and the TWS api on Windows which I run on Mac through parallels. I am using the terminal on Windows and am accessing it through cmd. I then type 'python' in the terminal. From here I type 'import ibapi' and the terminal is producing an error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibapi'' For additional context, I have added a path on the 'Edit environment variable' from the Windows start menu and it is called 'C:\Python\ibapi'.

I am expecting to be able to write scripts through the API so that I write algos to trade through the TWS API.

Comment: Do you mean you added `C:\Python\ipapi` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? (Assuming the `ibapi` module is in that folder, and not in some subfolder….) For what it’s worth, the Windows terminal reads the environment when it starts, so if you change the environment, you have to close and reopen the terminal before the changes will be seen. Also, remember that in Windows different paths would be separated by semicolons rather than colons like in UNIX-based OSs.

Comment: Yes, how would I go about adding to the PYTHONPATH environment variable? I have only seen the Path environment variable. Additionally the ibapi is in some some sub folders so Im hypothesizing that the path might be longer. Is this making sense? I have used ChatGPT to get me this far lol. I can provide any additional context as needed. I am green in the Python space so I apologize in advance for any obvious questions. TYSM!!

Comment: Before you start with other variables, the first thing you need to do is to remove that directory from the `Path` variable. If you've been modifying important environment variables based upon some non human guess engine's advice, you may well have already broken your system.

Comment: You can set `PYTHONPATH` the same way you set `PATH`; you’ll probably need to add it (with the New button), though. You might try setting it from the command line

`set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python\ibapi`

That will only last until you exit the terminal, but it is faster if you need to experiment.